# SQL calculate SUM of part of the data

Tags: mysql

I have a table `date, subs, unsubs`, where `date` is PK, and `subs` and `unsubs` are the number of subscribes and unsubscribes on that date.

I want to add a column to calculate the number of total subscribers on each day, that is, if sort date, `subsall` = `subsall` of last row + `subs` - `unsubs`.

For example: the table is

```
----------------
2012-01-01, 5, 2
2012-01-02, 6, 1
2012-01-03, 4, 3
----------------
```

I want to add a new column and the table becomes

```
-------------------
2012-01-01, 5, 2, 3
2012-01-02, 6, 1, 8
2012-01-03, 4, 3, 9
-------------------
```

What is the MySQL command to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a cumulative sum. Try this:

```
SELECT date, subs, unsubs, (@csum := @csum + subs - unsubs) cumulative
FROM table, (SELECT @csum :=0) c
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create trigger on INSERT action, please see the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the difference of the two columns and give it an alias of 'subsall' like this:

`SELECT date, subs, unsubs, (subs - unsubs) as 'subsall' FROM table`

Comment: This only calculate the difference of each day. I need to aggregate the previous rows.

Comment: I didn't understand your question completey... you want every new row to have the current subsall count?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (COUNT(subs) - COUNT(unsubs)) as total subscribers from table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Hope this works for you.